# Using Xpath Parent-Child Relationship in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, parent-child

I am very new to automation. I am trying to have a Selenium WebDriver click the flight destination on this travel website ([www.spicejet.com](http://www.spicejet.com)) for me, but it's not doing it. **Question: did I use the Parent-Child Relationship correctly in this code?** Thank you!

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Trial {
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Work\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");//URL in the browser

driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[value='BLR']")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@value='MAA']")).click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `a[value='BLR']` will work?

Comment: Yeah, I’m the course I’m taking the instructor explained that this is one of the acceptable syntaxes for the Xpath

Comment: In my humble opinion, you should change `ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT` to `ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXTaction`. By the way, there are no <a> element with `value` attribute with `BLR` value, maybe you should try this `#dropdownGroup1 > div > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(8) > a` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add delay.

try the code snippet below:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@value='BLR']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@value='MAA']")).click();
```